# Why below code's output is "not found" instead of "found"?

Tags: c

below code gives "Not found" output. But I expect it to give "found". Where is my    mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compare(char *x, char *face);
int i;

int main(void){

char array[5]="Two";
char *numbers[4]={"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};

compare(array, *numbers);

}

void compare(char *x, char *y){

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (*x==y[i])
    {
        printf("\n found");
        return;
    }

}
printf("\n not found\n");
}
```

Comment: `*numbers` is a pointer to the first character of `"One"`. None of the four characters in `{ 'O', 'n', 'e', '\0' }` equals `'T'`, so only `"\n not found\n"` is printed.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think `*numbers` == `*(numbers + 0)` == `numbers[0]` points to string `"One"` but not first char of `"One"`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan There are no strings in C ... numbers[0] is a `char*` that points to the 'O', just as Daniel said.

Comment: @JimBalter, Daniel Fischer, Sorry Actually misunderstood the comment, I got it means `numbers[0] == 'O'` ..now got it.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan " it means `numbers[0] == 'O'`" No, it doesn't mean that and that isn't true. Again, numbers[0] is a `char*` that *points to* the 'O'.

Comment: @JimBalter What Grijesh meant was that he first understood that I meant it meant `numbers[0] == 'O'` (and he rightfully objected to that), but now he understood how he misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: @JimBalter Sorry my bad English :P

Comment: Ok, maybe it really is bad English, and I underestimated how bad it is ... apparently "I got it means" was supposed to be "I thought it means".

Comment: @DanielFischer Does `*numbers` point only to the first character not the whole string literal?

Comment: @PHIfounder `*numbers` is a `char*`, so what it points to (if anything) is a `char`. That happens to be the initial element of a 0-terminated `char` array. It is common parlance to say such a pointer points to the string (literal or not), but strictly, it points to just the one `char` you get by dereferencing it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then in some cases we may face problems by considering that it points to string like in comparing two strings if their first letters are same but consequent letters are different like "two" and "three" ?

Comment: @PHIfounder `*(*numbers)` gives you the first char, not the whole literal string (which is not an object of the C language), so that's what `*numbers` points to ... the first char.

Comment: @PHIfounder One compares strings with `strcmp`, which deals fine with comparing "two" and "three". Of course one "may face problems" if just comparing the first chars when the intent was to compare the whole strings.

Comment: @JimBalter That's why I call it SEA not C , and even being an olympian   doesn't guarantee that you can swim the hell out of it. haha :D

Comment: @PHIfounder Actually `char[n]` can easily decay into `char*` in most operations. In `char array[10]` type of `array` is `char[10]` not `char*` but you can simply so assignment `char* ptr = array` and `*array` will give you first char value as to `*ptr`.

Comment: @JimBalter Language. "An expression of type `char[n]` is converted into an expression of type `char*` in most operations".

Comment: You have just compare `if ('T' == 'O' || 'T' == 'n' || 'T' == 'e' || 'T' == '\0')` so "not found" is printed out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `*x==y[i]` you are comparing the value of two chars instead of the data pointed to by two pointers. Use the [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function instead. It returns 0 if the two strings pointed to by the given two pointers are equal. So change it to `strcmp(x, y[i]) == 0`

Also you should change the `char *y` parameter to `char **y` or `char *y[]` because y is an array of pointers to strings, not just one pointer.

Finally, `compare(array, *numbers);` should be called as `compare(array, numbers);` because you want to pass a pointer to the array of strings, not just a pointer to one string (`numbers` is of type `char*[4]` but it will decay to type `char**` when passed as an argument).

Comment: "You are comparing value of C pointer and a symbol" -- nonsense; that compares two chars. "because y is an array of pointers to strings" -- no, it's not ... not as `compare` is currently called. More is needed than that.

Comment: That's not what I call fixed. See Ingo Leonhardt's and manuell's answers, which are actually correct.

Comment: Sorry to hear it. Perhaps you should do the replacements you mention and see what happens. Also, please learn what a "symbol" and a "char" are ... they aren't the same thing.

Comment: *x is a pointer. Its value is an address. So the value of the left hand side is 'T'. y[i] is a pointer to pointer to char. So the value of the right hand is an address. Am I right? So *x==y[i] comparison is not right

Comment: I wrote this because I think Sasha may need to edit his answer. He told there are two addresses(symbols mean address I assume), but instead there is a value and an address is compared.

Comment: @user1939432 `x` is a `char*` so `*x` is a char, not an address. `y[i]` is also a char, unless it is redeclared as `char** y`. Here's a clue (that wouldn't be necessary if people would actually read the other answers): not all of the changes that need to be made to the OP's code are in `compare`.

Comment: @user1939432 I urge you to accept the answer from either `Ingo Leonhardt` or `manuell` .. those answers are correct without any changes.

Comment: What is the value of numbers[0]? I suppose it is a char pointer. It's value is not a char. It is an adress in fact? Am I right?

Comment: @user1939432 Yes, the value of numbers[0] is a `char*`, but you are passing it to `compare` (as `*numbers`, which is the same thing) so it becomes the value of `x`. `*x` is `*numbers[0]`, which is 'O'. This is explained at length in the comments under your question.

Comment: @JimBalter, I guess we have this misunderstanding because of my language problems - I called `char` using word `symbol` which is actually not correct but this is a direct translation in my language. This is my fault in this case

Comment: But that's not your only error. You have to change *the way compare is called*, not just its arguments.

Comment: @user1939432 No, you misunderstand. Sasha already told you that `y` needs to be declared differently and `strcmp` needs to be used ... that will fix the comparison to be valid. *But it's not enough* to fix your program.

Comment: @JimBalter, that's true. Basically I didn't pretend to fix all of the problems and just told about what I have seen at a glance. In this sense I agree my answer is not good enough to be accepted but that's a question to the OP

Comment: @JimBalter, and feel free to put -1 here

Comment: "just told about what I have seen at a glance" -- That's not what SO or the people who ask questions deserve. Thanks for **finally** fixing your answer. Why would I give it a -1, now that you have done so?

Answer (score 4):

Combining the given answers and comments, the correct code mitght look lke this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compare(char *x, char **face);  // signature changed
int i;

int main(void){

   char array[5]="Two";
   char *numbers[4]={"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};

   compare(array, numbers);  // pass numbers, not *numbers

}

void compare(char *x, char **y) {  // signature changed, see above

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)  
    {
        if( strcmp( x, y[i] ) == 0 )   // use strcmp
        {
            printf("\n found");
            return;
        }

    }
    printf("\n not found\n");
}
```

Comment: +1 for an answer that isn't utter crap, like a couple of the ones here.

Comment: Except ... `**face`? What's a "face"?

Comment: ahh name is not important compiler ignores it sorry

Comment: @user1939432 Ah, sorry, I didn't realize that was the name used in the question ... for some reason I thought it was part of Ingo's changes.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compare(char *x, char **face);
int i;

int main(void){

char array[5]="Two";
char *numbers[4]={"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};

compare(array, &numbers[0]);

}

void compare(char *x, char **y){

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (*x==*y[i])
    {
        printf("\n found");
        return;
    }

}
printf("\n not found\n");
}
```

The above code will give you "found", but if you really want to compare string, use the below code:

```
void compare(char *x, char **y){

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (strcmp( x,y[i] ) == 0 )
    {
        printf("\n found");
        return;
    }

}
printf("\n not found\n");
}
```